# Как сделать кастомное окно?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Необходимо сделать кастомное окно для ввода IP адреса и порта и записи введённых значений в INI-файл. Подскажите в какую сторону копать и вообще возможно ли сделать такое в Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Необходимо сделать кастомное окно

Возможно не окно, а страница визорда?

Надо посмотреть на [функции](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm) из секции "Custom Setup Wizard Page functions":

- [CreateCustomPage](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustompage)
- [CreateCustomForm](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustomform)

В папке, где установлен Inno-Setup, есть папка Examples. В ней есть файл CodeClasses.iss с примерами использования этих функций.

Для CreateCustomPage:

```
Page := CreateCustomPage(Page.ID, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TNewCheckListBox');

CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
CheckListBox.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
CheckListBox.Height := ScaleY(97);
CheckListBox.Flat := True;
CheckListBox.Parent := Page.Surface;
CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('TNewCheckListBox', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('TNewCheckListBox', '', 1, True, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('TNewCheckListBox', '', 1, False, True, nil);
CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('TNewCheckListBox', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);

CheckListBox2 := TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
CheckListBox2.Top := CheckListBox.Top + CheckListBox.Height + ScaleY(8);
CheckListBox2.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
CheckListBox2.Height := ScaleY(97);
CheckListBox2.BorderStyle := bsNone;
CheckListBox2.ParentColor := True;
CheckListBox2.MinItemHeight := WizardForm.TasksList.MinItemHeight;
CheckListBox2.ShowLines := False;
CheckListBox2.WantTabs := True;
CheckListBox2.Parent := Page.Surface;
CheckListBox2.AddGroup('TNewCheckListBox', '', 0, nil);
CheckListBox2.AddRadioButton('TNewCheckListBox', '', 0, True, True, nil);
CheckListBox2.AddRadioButton('TNewCheckListBox', '', 0, False, True, nil);
```

Для CreateCustomForm:

```
procedure FormButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  OKButton, CancelButton: TNewButton;
begin
  Form := CreateCustomForm();
  try
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(128);
    Form.Caption := 'TSetupForm';
    Form.CenterInsideControl(WizardForm, False);

    Edit := TNewEdit.Create(Form);
    Edit.Top := ScaleY(10);
    Edit.Left := ScaleX(10);
    Edit.Width := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(2 * 10);
    Edit.Height := ScaleY(23);
    Edit.Text := 'TNewEdit';
    Edit.Parent := Form;

    OKButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    OKButton.Parent := Form;
    OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    OKButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 6 + 75 + 10);
    OKButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
    OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;
    OKButton.Default := True;

    CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    CancelButton.Parent := Form;
    CancelButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    CancelButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 10);
    CancelButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
    CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
    CancelButton.Cancel := True;

    Form.ActiveControl := Edit;

    if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then
      MsgBox('You clicked OK.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  finally
    Form.Free();
  end;
end;
```